# Handling singularities like (x-y) in the denominator while evaluating double integrals

Tags: numerical-integration, fourier-analysis, integral-transforms, singularity

I have to solve an Integral of the following type

```
R[w_] := (-2*I*w)/(\[CapitalGamma] - 2*I*w)^2
S[w_] := (\[CapitalGamma] + 2*I*w)/(\[CapitalGamma] - 2*I*w)^2
X[w_, T_] := Sin[w/T]/(\[Pi]*w)
Q[t_, T_] := 2*NIntegrate[Conjugate[R[w]]*R[w]*Conjugate[X[w, T]]*X[w, T], {w,-Infinity, 
 Infinity}] - 2I/\[Pi] Integrate[
Conjugate[R[w]]*Conjugate[X[w, T]]*R[x]*X[x, T]*Exp[I*t*(w - x)]/(
 w - x), {w, -Infinity, Infinity}, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

Here, the function X is an arbitrary function in L^2 space. Mathematica can't handle the singularity at w=x. I would like to know what method should I follow to handle this kind of singularity in the integral.

Comment: Two comments: Please define \[CapitalGamma] and is there any particular reason why the second integral is not a numerical integration (i.e. Integrate instead of NIntegrate)?

Answer (score 1):

The integrals are quite simple if the integrands are simplified. sin x / x =sinc x ist the Fourier transform of the unit characteristic function, so fourier integrals will be simple by  the convolution theorem: F(f g) = F(f)[Star] F[g]

```
FullSimplify[((-2*I*w)/(\[CapitalGamma] - 2*I*w)^2)*((2*I*
  w)/(\[CapitalGamma] + 2*I*w)^2) (Sin[w/T]/(\[Pi]*w))^2]

Out:= (4 Sin[w/T]^2)/(\[Pi]^2 (4 w^2 + \[CapitalGamma]^2)^2)

Assuming[\[CapitalGamma] > 0 Integrate[( 4 Sin[w/T]^2)/(\[Pi]^2 (4 w^2 + \[CapitalGamma]^2)^2), {w, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]]

Out:=ConditionalExpression[(T - (T + \[CapitalGamma])/E^(\[CapitalGamma]/T))/(2*Pi*T*\[CapitalGamma]^3), Re[T] > 0 && Im[T] == 0]
```

The second can be done sequentially

```
Assuming[{\[CapitalGamma] > 0}, FullSimplify[-2 I/\[Pi] Integrate[(4 Sin[w/T]^2)/(\[Pi]^2 (4 w^2 + \[CapitalGamma]^2)^2), Integrate[Exp[I*t*(w - x)]/(w - x), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}], {w, -Infinity, Infinity}]]]

Out:=ConditionalExpression[(1/(Pi^2*T*\[CapitalGamma]^3*Sign[t]))*
 ((((-1 + E^(\[CapitalGamma]/T))*T - \[CapitalGamma])*(Pi +         E^(I*t*w)*Sign[t]*((-I)*Cos[t*w]*(Log[(-t)*w] - Log[t*w]) +                    (-Log[-w] + Log[w])*Sin[t*w])))/ E^(\[CapitalGamma]/T)), Element[t, Reals] && w != Re[w]]
```